# RDS: permission denied for relation spatial_ref_sys when copying

Tags: postgresql, oracle-11g, amazon-rds, spatial, postgis

I am copying tables using ogr2ogr from Oracle to PostGIS. When I run try to load these I get,

```
ERROR 1: ERROR: permission denied for relation spatial_ref_sys when copying <table>@AWS
```

Comment: did this answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is a result of you not having access on that view. What you need to run to fix the permissions is

```
ALTER TABLE public.spatial_ref_sys OWNER TO rds_superuser;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON TABLE public.spatial_ref_sys TO public;
```

[Found here on the AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=170665)